# PHPExcel: Invalid cell coordinate A when inserting Excel into SQL database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, phpexcel

In PHP, I am looping through an excel file and inserting it into an MSSQL database. I am getting this error:

Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate A'

I don't get this error if I only run one of the queries in the loop. Separately, both queries work. So I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that the 2 queries are running. With the following code, there is one row inserted in both tables and then the error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Heres the code...

```
$dbc = odbc_connect(DB_DRIVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$inputFileName = 'lib/test.xlsx';

try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
//  Read a row of data into an array
$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                NULL,
                                TRUE,
                                FALSE);

$name = ms_escape_string($rowData[0][0]);
$city = ms_escape_string($rowData[0][2]);
$state = ms_escape_string($rowData[0][3]);
$phone = ms_escape_string($rowData[0][4]);
$website = ms_escape_string($rowData[0][5]);
$profit_status = ms_escape_string($rowData[0][6]);

$query = "insert into account2 ([name], [city], [state], [phone], [website], [type], [created_by], [last_modified_by]) 
values ('$name', '$city', '$state', '$phone', '$website', '6', '3', '3')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ins_id";

$data = odbc_exec($dbc, $query);

if (odbc_next_result($data)){
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_object($data)) {
        $account_id = $row->ins_id;
    }
    $query = "insert into account_hic2 (account_id, profit_status)
values ('$account_id', '$profit_status')";
}
$data2 = odbc_exec($dbc, $query);

odbc_free_result($data);
odbc_free_result($data2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message suggests that you're mis-setting the value of $row at some point, perhaps setting it to null, or to an empty string...

... or perhaps to a resource, as you're using the same variable name in your database fetch in the same loop where you're using it to keep track of the Excel row number

Comment: dang dude nice find. I was reusing $row on my while loop and messing up the variable. Thanks!